# How to ssh to remote ubuntu vm and change the shell from csh to bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, csh

Linux machine A & machine B has common called ses. On machine A we have the python script to ssh to machine B & run series of shell commands like cd to a dir, source few files & run a python script called clean.py

```
clean_command = "cd /ws/vprahlad-bgl/pats;source env.sh;source /auto/pysw/ats/env.sh;uname -a;python clean.py"
```

The id ses has passwordless login enabled between machine A & machine B. When `ssh ses@machine B %s clean_command` is giving error as `badly placed ()'s`

By default, ses on machine B has csh & the command inside clean.py works only with bash shell

I tried changing the shell from csh to bash in remote command but prompts for password, however other commands works fine

```
ses@A:~$ ssh ses@B 'uname -a;uptime;echo $SHELL; chsh -s /bin/bash'
Linux B 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 28 14:23:39 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
15:01:54 up 5 days, 22:44,  1 user,  load average: 0.10, 0.07, 0.05
/bin/csh
This is your AD password:
```

Is there way to ssh and change the shell to bash to source those files from csh

Answer (score 0):

`chsh` is meant for occasional, interactive, use. It determines your login shell. Changing it to `bash` is a very good idea on most systems, for many reasons -- newcomers to UNIX should only be using `csh` if your software environment insists on it (some SAP installations seem to standardize on it, for instance.)

So my solution is: login to B via SSH, run 'chsh', provide your password, choose `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` as your startup shell, then quit. From now on your scripts will run remotely using `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Your login shell is determined by the last entry in the /etc/passwd - line.
But you can call a bash-Script without login.
Just put the crucial statements of these env.sh and the "python clean.py"-statement in a script and call it with " bash script.bash "
This should work.